# Does anyone know how to fix: System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: 'The system cannot find the file specified' from visual studio?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    _ = Process.Start("C:/Users\riley/Desktop\astrobotrq.txt");
}
```

Comment: Watch the use of forward slash versus reverse slash.

Comment: @Grenade,It seems that your question has been solved, you can click '✔' to accept as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work for you `Process.Start(@"C:\Users\riley\Desktop\astrobotrq.txt");`. you are using the `/` instead of `\`

Comment: Thankyouuuuu so muchhhhh

Comment: It is no problem to use / or \ (always look at `Path.DirectorySeparatorChar` and `Path.AltDirectorySeparatorChar`). The main problem here was the \ char which is treated fromc# as an escape char. With the @ you *indicate that a string literal is to be interpreted verbatim*. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/verbatim

Comment: this is also valid `Process.Start("C:/Users/riley/Desktop/astrobotrq.txt");`

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
Process.Start("C:\\Users\\riley\\Desktop\\astrobotrq.txt");
```